# Relations $R$ and $S$ on $\mathbb{Z}$,both $R,S$ are both symmetric and transitive. Show that $|\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{S}|=|\mathcal{S}-\mathcal{R}|=1$

Tags: relations

Give an example of two relations $R$ and $S$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the following properties:
(i) both $R$ and $S$ are both symmetric and transitive.
(ii) if $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ represent $R$, respectively $S$, then
$$
|\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{S}|=|\mathcal{S}-\mathcal{R}|=1
$$

How does this  $1$ come? Don't even have the intuition of $
|\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{S}|=|\mathcal{S}-\mathcal{R}|=1
$.

Really hope someone could help\hint me a little bit!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal R=\{(0,0)\},\mathcal S=\{(1,1)\}$.